# ggplot2 map is blank

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes

I am using similar to code to other scripts with different shape files from Statistics Canada.  However, I can't get a simple script to work with a provincial map.  I think the problem is simple but I can't see it.

```
setwd("D:\\OneDrive\\lfs_stuff")
project_folder<-getwd()
data_folder<-project_folder
library(tidyverse)
#now start the map
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(mapproj)
library(ggplot2)
#get test data
mydata<-read_csv("map_data.csv",col_types=list(col_character(),col_double()))
print(mydata)
# shape file came from this link for a digital shape file
# http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lpr_000a16a_e.zip
target_url<-"http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lpr_000a16a_e.zip"
url_file<-"lpr_000a16a_e.zip"
download_target<-paste0(project_folder,"/",url_file)
    download.file(target_url,download_target,mode="wb",quiet=FALSE)
    unzip(download_target,overwrite=TRUE,exdir=data_folder)
provincial_shape_file<-gsub(".zip",".shp",download_target)
provincial_shp<-readOGR(dsn=provincial_shape_file,layer="lpr_000a16a_e")
#convert it to the reqired data structure. the id vbl will contain the provincial codes
prov_base_map<-fortify(provincial_shp,region="PRUID")
map_data_1<-merge(prov_base_map,as_data_frame(mydata),by="id")
map1<-ggplot()+
geom_map(data=map_data_1,map=map_data_1,stat="identity",
aes(map_id=id,x=long,y=lat,fill=(pch),group=group),
colour="black",size=0.3)+
coord_map()
print(map1)
```

The download for the shape file is in the script.  The mydata file is shown below

```
"id","pch"
"10",0.667259786476859
"11",5.63186813186813
"12",2.12053571428572
"13",-0.563697857948142
"24",0.150669774230772
"35",1.15309092428315
"46",0.479282622139765
"47",1.70242950877815
"48",1.84482533036765
"59",1.96197656978394
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `sf` (though I think the ultimate issue is not having the `id` being identified correctly):

```
library(sf)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

read.csv(text='"id","pch"
"10",0.667259786476859
"11",5.63186813186813
"12",2.12053571428572
"13",-0.563697857948142
"24",0.150669774230772
"35",1.15309092428315
"46",0.479282622139765
"47",1.70242950877815
"48",1.84482533036765
"59",1.96197656978394',
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         colClasses = c("character", "double")) -> xdf

# cross-platform-friendly d/l with caching built-in
try(httr::GET(
  url = "http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lpr_000a16a_e.zip",
  httr::write_disk("~/Data/lpr_00a16a_e.zip"),
  httr::progress()
)) -> res

fils <- unzip("~/Data/lpr_00a16a_e.zip", exdir = "~/Data/lpr")

ca_map <- st_read(grep("shp$", fils, value=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ca_map <- st_simplify(ca_map, TRUE, 10) # you don't need the coastlines to be that detailed
ca_map <- left_join(ca_map, xdf, by=c("PRUID"="id"))

ggplot(ca_map) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pch)) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(direction=-1, option="magma") +
  coord_sf()
```

[image]

As an aside, even though I simplified the shapefile (for faster plotting) I'd hunt around for a light[er]-weight GeoJSON version of the provinces since the one you grabbed has *super* fine-grained coastlines and you absolutely don't need that for a choropleth.

Comment: I really appreciated the simplify suggestion.  I had used the gdal program.  I was not aware that the sf library would work so nicely.  Can you explain why the id was not identified.  In previous runs with other shape files, the fortify seemed to identify the id correctly.